# Strange response with ASP query from MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'm using ASP to show the result from MySQL. Like the way using Oracle, I have create a system DSN successfully:

[image]

And here is my asp codes

```
<%
'----------------------------------------------
' test connection 
'----------------------------------------------
Response.Charset="utf-8"
on error resume next
response.write "Test for connection to mysql" & vbcrlf
strConnect="driver={mysql odbc 5.1 driver};dsn=MYSQL;uid=your user name;password=your pass word;"
set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open strConnect

strSQL = "select name,address from teacher where id=4"
set rs = objConn.execute(strSQL)

if not rs.eof then
  response.write "Find some records!" & vbcrlf
  response.write "the data is :" & rs("name") & vbcrlf
  response.write "Yes!" & vbcrlf
else 
  response.write "Opps, No record found!" & vbcrlf
end if 
on error goto 0
%>
```

and the result from the page:

[image]

First of all, the select query `strSQL` will **NOT** get anything because there are no records with `id=4`. But, as you can see, the rs is NOT empty, and the second `response.write` was missing, I am so confused. 
Actually, if you put the three `response.write` in a loop like

```
do until rs.eof
  ...
  rs.movenext
loop
```

it will be an endless loop. So, looks like the rs is not empty, but something we cannot see?

**Update:**
I looked the log in my mysql, and found after I update the page, the sql queries are only these:
[image]

Totally not found my strSQL, why?

Comment: Please include your code as text **not** a screen shot. It is hard to copy and paste code from a screen shot into an editor/IDE

Comment: @JonP , have done that!

Comment: You should try removing the `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`. My bet is you will see that you have an error in the SQL and so no rs and that's why the write fails as well.

Comment: @bitfiddler  I did not change any other codes just the key cods in my answer, and remove the system DSN in ODBC manager, then it works. I do not know why, but thanks very much!

Comment: Kaka, it's a good idea to remove your username and password details from your image and post.

Comment: @Paul ,Thanks ! Have done it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are actually creating a recordset in `rs`. Try replacing that set statement with somethining like this:

```
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open sqlStr, objConn
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! And I modified my code like you said ,nothing changed.

Comment: What is the data type of teacher.id? If it's not numeric, then the select is throwing an error becaue it isn't quoted.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have solved it! Look my answer. It's really strange!

Comment: Yes, as I said above and in my comment, the resume next was keeping you from seeing the error. You should avoid that unless you otherwise test for errors. Glad you solved it.

Comment: so , when to user the `resume next` ? I have wrote many asp codes with oracle, and always using this `resume next`, no problem happened before until I want to query from MySQL yesterday,  @bitfiddler

Comment: By using it you are basically saying "ignore errors and keep going". Sometimes the error is real and should be handled. Leave it out and you will see the error message right away. It's best to only use it when you have finished code and you have some other way to test for errors. For example, in your code after trying to open the recordset, you could check that rs is a valid recordset.

Comment: got it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is my way to solve this strange problem:

1. DELETE the system DSN in the ODBC manager
2. Modify the key codes like this:

   ```
   strConnect="driver={mysql odbc 5.1 driver};SERVER=your server's address;DATABASE=test_db;user=your username;password=yourpassword;"
   set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   objConn.Open strConnect
   strSQL = "select name,address from teacher where id=4"
   set rs = objConn.execute(strSQL)
   ```

Look at the update in my question, with those codes I found the logs in mysql is strange, so, it must be the strSQL did not be wrote correctly. 
I don't know why, but it works!